# Excel Run-time error '1004' - CountIf properties

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

*I've searched on google and didn't find solution* while running my VBA code i get this error "Run-time error '1004' Unable to get the countif property of the worksheetFunction class.."

Here is code:

```
 Dim Pocetak, Kraj, Data_pocetak, Data_kraj, Trazeni_tekst_1, Trazeni_tekst_2 As String
    Dim Broj_offset_redka, Broj_kata, Broj_prostorije, Broj_stavke As Integer
    
    Broj_stavke = 1
    Broj_kata = 1
    Broj_prostorije = 1
    Trazeni_tekst_1 = "Prostor " & Broj_kata & "." & Broj_prostorije
    Trazeni_tekst_2 = "Prostor " & Broj_kata & "." & Broj_prostorije + 1
    Debug.Print Trazeni_tekst_1, Trazeni_tekst_2
    
    Do While Broj_kata <= Ukupan_broj_katova + 1
    
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet5.Range("B:B"), Trazeni_tekst_1) > 0 And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet5.Range("B:B"), Trazeni_tekst_2) > 0 Then
           
           Pocetak = Sheet5.Range("B:B").Find(Trazeni_tekst_1, lookAt:=xlWhole).Address
           Kraj = Sheet5.Range("B:B").Find(Trazeni_tekst_2, lookAt:=xlWhole).Address
           Data_pocetak = Sheet5.Range("B:B").Find(Trazeni_tekst_1, lookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).Address
           Data_kraj = Sheet5.Cells.Find(Trazeni_tekst_2, lookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(-1, 4).Address
           Debug.Print Pocetak, Kraj, Data_pocetak, Data_kraj
           
           Sheet5.Range(Pocetak, Data_kraj).Copy
           Sheet5.Paste Destination:=Sheet5.Range(Pocetak, Data_kraj).Offset(0, 6)
           Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak, Data_kraj).Offset(0, 6).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
           
           Broj_offset_redka = 0
           
           Do Until Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak).Offset(Broj_offset_redka, 6).Value = ""
                Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak).Offset(Broj_offset_redka, 8).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak, Data_kraj), Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak).Offset(Broj_offset_redka, 6).Value)
                Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak).Offset(Broj_offset_redka, 10).Value = Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak).Offset(Broj_offset_redka, 8).Value * Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak).Offset(Broj_offset_redka, 9).Value
                Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak).Offset(Broj_offset_redka, 5).Value = Broj_stavke
                Broj_stavke = Broj_stavke + 1
                Broj_offset_redka = Broj_offset_redka + 1
                
           Loop
```

and so on

This line is highlighted while debuging.

```
Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak).Offset(Broj_offset_redka, 8).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak, Data_kraj), Sheet5.Range(Data_pocetak).Offset(Broj_offset_redka, 6).Value)
```

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On my PC, this is working fine, so your code is correct.

... But when I look at the rest of your code, I have the impression that you are working in Polish or some other Slavic language, and as you might know, Excel has the possibility to use locale dependent functions.

So, I would advise you to check the translation of [`=CountIf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif) in your local language (maybe Excel VBA intellisense might be useful too).

Comment: Yeah, writing in Croatian. I didn't have this problem on my previous computer with *i think* same excel version and language settings.

Comment: You are using the terms "Excel version" and "language settings", while I am referring to "Excel language", are you sure you don't have a Croatian Excel? I mean, when using standard Excel functions, are you using `=Sum()`, `=Average()` or are you using `=Iznos()` and `=Prosjek()`? (Please don't kill me if those words are wrong :-) )

Comment: Im using =Sum() and similar.. So im using "English" as Excel language

Comment: I only realise it now: you're facing runtime errors, not compilation errors, so there's something wrong with the values, not with the name of the `CountIf()` function.